# Combining Python 3 formats (trying to use a thousand seperator and two decimals at same time)

Tags: python, format, python-3.4

In Python 3, how can I do multiple formats at once:

So I want to make a number have no decimal places and have a thousands separator:

num = 80000.00

I want it to be 80,000

I know I can do these two things serepatly, but how would I combine them?

This question was asked for python 2.7 but I don't see an explanation for python 3. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
In [155]: '{:,.0f}'.format(80000.00)
Out[155]: '80,000'
```

The `,` in the [format string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) ``` {:,.0f}`` tells ```format`to use comma separators, and the`.0`tells`format` to include zero digits after the decimal point.

Alternatively, you could set a locale and then use `locale.format`:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
print(locale.format("%d", 80000.00, grouping=True))
# 80,000
```

but note that the placement of the commas then depends on the locale. For example, if your machine has the `en_IN` (English India) locale installed, then

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_IN')
for num in (80000.00, 10000000):
    print(locale.format("%d", num, grouping=True))
    print('{:,.0f}'.format(num))
```

yields

```
80,000
80,000
1,00,00,000
10,000,000
```

In contrast, `'{:,.0f}'.format` always places the comma separator between every three digits.

Comment: thanks for the swift reply,  I'm a little new to Python and I get the '{:,.0f}'.format(800000.00) part now thanks for explaining most of the parts. What does the : indicate within '{:,.0f}'.format(800000.00)?

Comment: The colon is just a fixed part of the format string which [separates the `field_name` and `conversion` from the `format_spec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: Interesting, I'm guessing the {} are being used instead of () because it is multiple format operations?:                                                         Example: num1 = format(num1, ',.2f')            num1 = 800000                   num2 = '{:,.0f}'.format(800000.00)                  num2 = 800,000

Comment: Not quite. There is a [`format` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) which -- like all functions -- are called by placing parentheses `()` after the function. `'{:,.0f}'` is a string. Everything in Python is an object. The string is a `str` object. Objects have methods. `'{:,.0f}'.format` is the [`str` object's format method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Methods, like functions, are called by placing parentheses after the method. Thus you pass the `num` argument and call the method with  `'{:,.0f}'.format(num)`.

Comment: `format(num1, ',.2f')` is an example of calling the [`format` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format). `'{:,.0f}'.format(800000.00)` is an example of calling the [`str.format` method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Ahhhhh, okay that makes sense, I was wondering why they were different. Thank you for taking the time to explain everything and differences between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
"{:,}".format(int(num))
```

works fine for me.